# rsync ownership change even when file content is not changed

Tags: linux, scripting, rsync

I have two disks that the files are on them are almost identical except that the ownership on files are different because the uid and gid were originally different.

I want to find a way to rsync from source disk to dest disk and also automatically change the ownership of the files on the destination disk, even if the file has the same size and last modified time.

For example, my /mnt/disk1/a.txt has owner of bob:bob, /mnt/disk2/a.txt has owner of alice:alice, all other aspects of a.txt are the same. Will rsync recognize the file ownership difference?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Did `rsync` update the ownership or not? Try it on a test directory if you're worried about unintentional changes.

Comment: rsync just ignores syncing that file